# Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My App.js (simplified but still gives error with just this much.)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ user });
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have updated my index.js now:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const Index = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Index;
```

It gives the error `Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM`

Comment: can you please share your config file where 'module' and 'target' configured?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I've edited the post to show my next.config.json.

Comment: could you show your App component?

Comment: I've added my app.js now.

Comment: Does your App component have a render method? Do you still get the error if you add one?

Comment: My original one does have a render method, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NextJS, you don't have to add the `ReactDOM.render` part as in normal ReactJS applications. NextJS does this themselves while rendering the application.

The bare minimum, you have to have the appication running is to add a `index.js` in `pages` directory:

```
const Index = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Hello Next.js</p>
  </div>
);

export default Index;
```

Note that `Index` component here is exported by default.

[Learn NextJS Docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started/first-page)

Comment: Heres my updated index.js, gives `Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM`

Comment: you also don't need to use `react-router`, NextJS comes with their own routing module. Please read upon [basics](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started) before you get started

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom with nextjs. you just only need to add

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') return null;
return <Container {...props} />;
```

in your pages/{dummy}/index.js file to avoid "Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIVSg.png)